# How do you describe states of a change while the change is in progress?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For simplicity I will give an example.

I have a document with a title and my boss asked me to update it.

Before the change happened I would call the titles "current title" and "future title".

After the change happened, I would call the titles "previous title" and "current title".

Now if the boss calls me while I am in the middle of updating the title, how could I describe these two him?

Comment: I would call them "current title" and "future title". While you are in the middle of updating the title, the change has not yet occurred.

Comment: Tentative title (or placeholder title)?

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a **working title**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_title) (albeit in a different context):

> A **working title**, sometimes called a **production title** or a **tentative title**, is the temporary title of a product or project used during its development, usually used in filmmaking, television production, video game development, or the creation of a novel or music album.

Although the context of that article is different from that of the question, *working title* is still a common term for a title that you are *working on at the moment*, regardless of how long it takes for that work to be finished.

While the alternative of *production title* is not relevant in this question's context, *tentative title* is. So too would be *title in progress* or *draft title*.